# Hide duplicate LI was same id with js or jQuery Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dom

i Want hide duplicate elements on my view.

Hide duplicate element from  Content One  with same ID from li  with js or jquery and show only one for id Rails on page load or reload.

**My problem Example:**

```
<li id="1"> Content One </li>
<li id="1"> Content One </li>
<li id="1"> Content One </li>
<li id="2"> Content Two </li>
<li id="2"> Content Two </li>
```

I want to hide two or more lines if it is the same id and show only one.

**After remove or hide duplicate i want this result.**

```
<li id="1"> Content One </li>
<li id="2"> Content Two </li>
```

**See my code.**

```
<ul id="eventList" class="timeline">
  <li id="<%= @myid %>" class="timeline-inverted">
  <li id="<%= @myid %>" class="timeline" >
</ul>
```

Can help me someone.

Comment: Your problem is moot as you cannot have elements with the same `id`.

Comment: the li ids will be populated by an each which will bring the same id more than once, I want to bring only 1 unique id if it is duplicated when the list is populated

Comment: That's my point. You should fix the output from the server, as by the time it's rendered in HTML it's invalid, and JS has issues accessing elements with the same `id` (as it should never happen)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```js
var ul_list = '';
var liList = $('ul li'), listForRemove = [];

$(liList).each(function () {
    
  var text = $(this).text();

  if (ul_list.indexOf('|'+ text + '|') == -1)
    ul_list += '|'+ text + '|';
  else
    listForRemove.push($(this));
    
});
    
$(listForRemove).each(function () { $(this).remove(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="1"> Content One </li>
<li id="1"> Content One </li>
<li id="1"> Content One </li>
<li id="2"> Content Two </li>
<li id="2"> Content Two </li>
</ul>
```